# Hibernate log dirty entity properties?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, logging, logback

I'm using JPA with Hibernate as my provider.

I have a case where an entity is being marked as dirty and I'm not sure why. Is there a logger that can be turned on that will print why an entity is being marked as dirty? In other words, what properties on the entity have changed to cause it to be marked as dirty?

I'm using SLF4j and logback for logging. The best I've been able to find so far is

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister" level="trace" />
```

Which will give me log statements like this:

```
26-Apr-2013 09:24:50.054 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8] TRACE o.h.p.entity.AbstractEntityPersister - com.example.MyEntity.myEntityProperty is dirty
```

But it also includes a fairly large amount of other trace statements that I would rather not get logged.

Answer (score 1):

Found one that *would* work if not for what appears to be a bug in the Hibernate code.

```
org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.logDirtyProperties(Serializable, int[], EntityPersister)
```

This method is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for and turning trace on for `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener` has a very small impact. Unfortunately turning on trace using:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener" level="trace" />
```

results in log messages like this:

```
26-Apr-2013 09:51:33.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8] TRACE o.h.e.i.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener - Found dirty properties [[com.example.MyEntity#1]] : [Ljava.lang.String;@221c75
26-Apr-2013 09:51:33.370 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8] TRACE o.h.e.i.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener - Updating entity: [com.example.MyEntity#1]
```

The problem being that `[Ljava.lang.String;@221c75` is supposed to be a list of property names.